# How to add new line for the following string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I am new to regex and I am trying to add new line for the following string pattern.

```
(request-target): put /api/v1/9e7336e2-ee96-406d-bba8-e75cf14b2a94/account/e15be91a-b63c-4b4b-ae3f-a0426ae98bcd/address/73844762-8305-4528-ac44-1f1024297abd/payment/041c5e65-0556-4df1-a504-6a31fa48fe64/domestic\nDate: 2018-01-31T14:16:50.259-06:00\nDigest: Ghjaioq+mFvjNOIkKZivIYa/khMz1siWw/zA502E+k0HzKIWhoXXYFeoFaLztXWBcQpcSjDqpTEx688OuU1x9A==
```

**Expected output**:

```
(request-target): put /api/v1/9e7336e2-ee96-406d-bba8-e75cf14b2a94/account/e15be91a-b63c-4b4b-ae3f-a0426ae98bcd/address/73844762-8305-4528-ac44-1f1024297abd/payment/041c5e65-0556-4df1-a504-6a31fa48fe64/domestic
Date: 2018-01-31T14:16:50.259-06:00
Digest: Ghjaioq+mFvjNOIkKZivIYa/khMz1siWw/zA502E+k0HzKIWhoXXYFeoFaLztXWBcQpcSjDqpTEx688OuU1x9A==
```

I did tried the combination of match and replace `\n` and nothing match.

Can anyone please help?

Update: 
[image]

Adding final output when matching `//n` or `////n` and replacing with `\n`

output:

```
(request-target): put /api/v1/9e7336e2-ee96-406d-bba8-e75cf14b2a94/account/e15be91a-b63c-4b4b-ae3f-a0426ae98bcd/address/73844762-8305-4528-ac44-1f1024297abd/payment/041c5e65-0556-4df1-a504-6a31fa48fe64/domesticDate: 2018-01-31T14:16:50.259-06:00Digest: Ghjaioq+mFvjNOIkKZivIYa/khMz1siWw/zA502E+k0HzKIWhoXXYFeoFaLztXWBcQpcSjDqpTEx688OuU1x9A==
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want but see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/wJdslc/1

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer however I have added \n end of line assuming it will it added to new line

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but could you clarify what you're trying to do? This seems a little broad at the moment. Step back and read your question as if you have no prior knowledge.

Comment: In what way you are trying to deal with that string?

Comment: Please check the update I have added.

Comment: @revo basically we have an APIGW which has inbuilt custom Regex which we can to match and replace. So some reason I am puzzled everytime I do find and replace the \n get's added

Comment: So, you have a literal 2-char substring `\n` and you want to replace it with a newline symbol, right?  Try `\\n` or `\\\\n` and replace with `\n`

Comment: Good. Please copy / paste output in *text result* textarea into your question.

Comment: @revo you mean match / and replace with /n output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I tried the solution you gave however the `/n` is still getting added.

Comment: Final output in *Text Result (After Replace)*

Comment: @revo I have updated the post.

Comment: It actually replaces correct thing but it seems newline character isn't rendered into output area.

Comment: yeah not sure why that is happening

Comment: Understand, you're not looking for a newline, you're looking for a backslash character \, followed by a n. Since the backslash character is a special character in regex, it has to be escaped to be found in the text. The regex is simply [\\n](https://regex101.com/r/6h9ay4/1). No use fighting city hall, it works the same way on every regex engine there is.